# calling a proc from inside puts TCL command and put it in file

Tags: tcl

I am trying to call a proc from inside a puts statement and put it in a file  using TCL  as follows

```
set fp_jason [open jason.txt w]
proc MY_FUNCTION { } {
puts "Experiment success"
}
puts $fp_jason " [MY_FUNCTION] "
```

Output of above script in jason.txt is nothing

Experiment Success is printed in shell

Intead desired output i  want jason.txt to contain is

```
$cat jason.txt
Experiment success
```

Could to help me get the desired output in jason.txt

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `puts` without specifying the channel, you will `puts` to `stdout`. If you want to puts a string to a file, you would usually do:

```
puts $fp_jason "Experiment success"
```

So if you replace `Experiment success` by a function, that function has to `return` the string `Experiment success`, so automatically this becomes:

```
set fp_jason [open jason.txt w]

proc MY_FUNCTION { } {
    return "Experiment success"
}
puts $fp_jason "[MY_FUNCTION]"
```

I removed the spaces before and after the function since it doesn't look like you need them. Also, if you are not putting anything more to the file than the result of the function (or anything that might be interpreted as additional arguments by the interpreter), you can safely use:

```
puts $fp_jason [MY_FUNCTION]
```

Use quotes if you do something like this because you are using spaces within the string:

```
proc MY_FUNCTION { } {
    return "4"
}
puts $fp_jason "A table has [MY_FUNCTION] legs"
```

**This is wrong because each of the words will be interpreted as arguments to the command `puts`:**

```
proc MY_FUNCTION { } {
    return "4"
}
puts $fp_jason A table has [MY_FUNCTION] legs
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply command substitution by means of using square brackets.

```
puts [MY_FUNCTION]
```

Comment: Hi dinesh thanks for the quick answer but i have modified my question can u look above question?